# Creating Lion-esque toolbars

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, toolbar

I'm wanting to create Reeder/MAS -esque toolbars for my new app, but am unsure how to accomplish this, or what to search on google.

Can anyone help me, please? :)

Gareth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow). It creates a window with a thick theme frame and vertically centered buttons.